# LinkSys RV042 Dual WAN Router: Utilize backup link in Smartlink mode

Tags: routing, load-balancing, linksys

I have a LinkSys RV042 Dual Wan Router in my office. I am using it in smartlink mode, so that when primary fails, the backup link takes over.

The problem is that backup link is highly under-utilized. I have a dev machine that periodically replicates data from a production server. I would like to route all of this dev's machine's traffic through the backup link. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you put the RV042 in Load Balancing mode, you can set it to send traffic from an IP address or service over a specific WAN interface. You can find more details in this [Cisco support doc](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9923/products_qanda_item09186a0080a36632.shtml) (you might need to register before you can view it)

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this before but why don't you see if you can setup a dedicated rounte from the dev machine to the net using a custom route?  I've done custom routing for VPN issues, but never trying to force a machine out a specific WAN put.

In the RV042, select Setup, then Advanced Routing, you should be able to add a route for the dev machine to the backup WAN port/IP.